# Unable to properly do a fetch with Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, next.js

I am having trouble doing a fetch according to the documentation available on the Next.js website.  I have tried to console the props, which I can't get to show up.  I don't have experience with Next, trying to mirror it to React, but unfortunately it's not working. How can I do a fetch using getStaticProps?  I have a tutorial that is using getInitialProps for an older version of Next.js, but I am trying to follow their new documentation. Here is the starter code I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import fetch from 'node-fetch'

class Index extends Component {
    state = {}

    getStaticProps = async () => {
        // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
        console.log('fetching data')
        const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
        const posts = await res.json()


        return {
            props: {
                posts,
            },
        }

    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Our Index Page!!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default Index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> If you export an async function called `getStaticProps` from a page, Next.js will pre-render this page at build time using the props returned by `getStaticProps`.

That means that instead of having your `getStaticProps` inside the component, **export** it as such:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
// import fetch from 'node-fetch'

class Index extends Component {
    state = {}

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Our Index Page!!</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    // Call an external API endpoint to get posts.
    console.log('fetching data')
    const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    const posts = await res.json()
    return {
        props: {
            posts,
        },
    }
}

export default Index
```